# How to do transactional createQueryBuilder in doctrine onFlush Listener?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have problem with doctrine listener [onFlush]. I need do update another entities included in transactional. When I use like this example, update run before transaction. Can help me somebody?

```
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    $ea = $this->getEventAdapter($args);
    $om = $ea->getObjectManager();
    $uow = $om->getUnitOfWork();

    foreach ($ea->getScheduledObjectUpdates($uow) as $object) {

        //... some operation on entity
        $uow->propertyChanged($object, 'field', 'oldValue', 'newValue');
        //...........................

        // global update with createQueryBuilder on another entities
        // I need added this also to transaction
        $qb = $om->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->update(".........")
            ->set(".........")
            ->where(".........")
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
    }
}
```